# Python. Проблемы с записью строки в файл

Tags: python, файлы, запись

Использую стандартные методы записи

```
handle = open("file.py", "w")
handle.write(data)
handle.close()
```

```
handle = open("file.py", "w")
handle.writelines(data)
handle.close()
```

Только на выходе получаю в файле

> ['import os\n', 'import sys\n', '\n', 'def func0():\n', ' print("1")\n', ...

Проблема заключается в том, что я преобразовывал в один из моментов путём `str(data)`

В чем может быть решение проблемы?

Comment: мм, а что собственно лежит в `data`?

Comment: Хм, непосредственно то, что и записывает, как тогда преобразовать к ожидаемому виду?

Comment: это уже другой вопрос

Comment: readlines сработал хорошо, но writelines косит

Comment: построчно записывать, тогда проблем не будет

Comment: Нашёл, суть понятна, у меня в один момент идет преобразование из массива строк в строку путем str(data). Может кто подсказать обратное преобразование?

Comment: @finally, по выводу очевидно, что там список строк ;) Причём вместе с переводом строки.

Comment: Эээ.. Ты чего вопрос меняешь после ответа??

Comment: @Qwertiy, извини, я еще 10 минут назад это понял

Comment: И чего ты понял? Если через writelines работает, то это надо постить в ответе, а не в вопросе.

Comment: @Qwertiy, не работает.

Comment: @Qwertiy, есть способ после преобразования массива строк в строку врнуть все по местам?

Comment: А я тебе в ответе что написал?

Comment: @Qwertiy, все бы здорово, но и этот метод не панацея

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> handle.write(data)
> ```

```
handle.write("".join(data))
```